# Can't open an attached html file in a sharepoint list using browser

Tags: html, sharepoint-list, download

Every time I try to open an uploaded html file in one of my sharepoint lists it gets downloaded instead of opening the browsers. I found some solutions that were not optimal/doesn't work for me.

Solution 1: Using a extension like Undisposition. Does exactly what I want but I need to install the extension for my colleagues.

Solution 2: Always open files of this type setting in the browser. Automatically opens the file but still needs to download it.

Solution 3: Changing the Extension to .aspx. Every time I try to upload an .aspx file it says Access denied even though I am the site owner, solutions say that I need to enable Custom Scripts through the admin center which I don't have access to. (This solution is not possible unless there a work around this)

Solution 4: Have the files upload to OneDrive instead. For some reason these ones are opened in browser normally. (I prefer files to uploaded in the list item it self)

The files will be uploaded using power automate incase this helps with finding a solution.

Comment: Please, may you answer my stupid question: the html files is to be rendered when click on it?

Comment: When the attachment is clicked in the sharepoint list item like this: 
[Example this](https://imgur.com/2RS7QoT) @AntonioLeonardo